# Accessing feature classes with a geoprocessing webtool

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I'm writing a script which takes a user input from the geoprocessing widget (a polygon that the user draws), and queries the intersecting layers using arcpy.SelectByLocation_managment(). The tool then queries the attribute tables of those featureclasses and combines the selected rows from those featureclasses into one pandas dataframe, before finally exporting it to a csv file.

My tool works fine in ArcGIS Pro, but I'm having trouble accessing my featureclasses once the tool is uploaded as a geoprocessing service. I don't understand where I need to point my tool to query the attribute tables. I've been watching videos on creating geoprocessing tasks, and looking at documentation for hours, and I still don't understand what I need to reference.

The error I receive from the geoprocessing widget when I try to run my tool in WebAppBuilder is that I have no objects to concatenate, which I assume means that I am not actually referencing the featureclasses correctly:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 130, in File "", line 121, in ScriptTool File "", line 108, in combineDataframes File "E:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 295, in concat sort=sort, File "E:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 342, in __init__ raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate") ValueError: No objects to concatenate
Failed to execute (landChargesSelect WebService v2).
Failed.
```

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
import os
# Set the workspace for ListFeatureClasses
# NOTE - Cannot use 215 enterprise server as workspace, likely due to UNC path, use C: instead
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\fitzpatricko\landChargesSelectTool.gdb"
datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='feature')
datasets = [''] + datasets if datasets is not None else []
# Variable for output of selected feature layers
outputLayers = r"C:\Users\fitzpatricko\landChargesSelectToolOutputs.gdb"
def createSelection():
    # To allow overwriting outputs change overwriteOutput option to True.
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    #targetPoly = str(param0)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Creating selection using the following target layer: ' + param0)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Creating selection for the following feature layers: ')
    for ds in datasets:
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
            if fc != param0:
                arcpy.AddMessage(str(fc))
                arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(in_layer=fc, 
                                                       overlap_type="INTERSECT", 
                                                       select_features=param0, 
                                                       search_distance="", 
                                                       selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", 
                                                       invert_spatial_relationship="NOT_INVERT")
                
def arcgis_table_to_df(in_fc, input_fields=None, query=""):
    """Function will convert an arcgis table into a pandas dataframe with an object ID index, and the selected
    input fields using an arcpy.da.SearchCursor.
    :param - in_fc - input feature class or table to convert
    :param - input_fields - fields to input to a da search cursor for retrieval
    :param - query - sql query to grab appropriate values
    :returns - pandas.DataFrame"""
    OIDFieldName = arcpy.Describe(in_fc).OIDFieldName
    if input_fields:
        final_fields = [OIDFieldName] + input_fields
    else:
        final_fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(in_fc)]
    data = [row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_fc,final_fields,where_clause=query)]
    fc_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=final_fields)
    fc_dataframe = fc_dataframe.set_index(OIDFieldName,drop=True)
    return fc_dataframe
def arcgis_table_to_dataframe(in_fc, input_fields, query="", skip_nulls=False, null_values=None):
    """Function will convert an arcgis table into a pandas dataframe with an object ID index, and the selected
    input fields. Uses TableToNumPyArray to get initial data.
    :param - in_fc - input feature class or table to convert
    :param - input_fields - fields to input into a da numpy converter function
    :param - query - sql like query to filter out records returned
    :param - skip_nulls - skip rows with null values
    :param - null_values - values to replace null values with.
    :returns - pandas dataframe"""
    OIDFieldName = arcpy.Describe(in_fc).OIDFieldName
    if input_fields:
        final_fields = [OIDFieldName] + input_fields
    else:
        final_fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(in_fc)]
    np_array = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(in_fc, final_fields, query, skip_nulls, null_values)
    object_id_index = np_array[OIDFieldName]
    fc_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np_array, index=object_id_index, columns=input_fields)
    return fc_dataframe
def cleanCombinedDataframe(dfToClean, param1):
    arcpy.AddMessage('Reference: ' + str(param1))
    """
    Function outcomes:
    - Reindexes the concatenated dataframe, using the name of the feature layer as the new index
    - Drops columns containing ArcGIS related data
    - Create empty reference column
    - Populates the empty 'Reference' column with a string passed as a parameter to the script tool by the user
    """
    dfToClean.set_index('Layer_Name', inplace=True)
    dfToClean.drop(['OBJECTID', 'Shape_Area', 'Shape_Leng', 'Shape', 'Shape_Length', 
                    'X', 'Y', 'LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    dfToClean.assign(Reference=None)
    dfToClean['Reference'] = str(param1)
    referenceCol = dfToClean.pop('Reference')
    dfToClean.insert(loc=0, column="Reference", value=referenceCol)
    return dfToClean
# Empty list to be populated with feature-layer attribute tables, converted into dataframes
dfList = []
def combineDataframes():
    # The file name must be stated at the end of the path for this method to work!
    outputTable = os.path.join(r"H:\CorporateGIS\GIS\Work Requests\2022\Land Charges Select Tool\Table Exports", param0 + '_' + param1 + ".csv")
    """
    Function outcomes:
    - Transforms featureLayer attribute tables from the current map into dataframes.
    - Adds each new dataframe to an empty list
    - Concatenates all of the dataframes added to this list into one dataframe
    """
    arcpy.AddMessage('Combining attribute tables')
    for ds in datasets:
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
            if fc != param0:
                featClassdf = arcgis_table_to_df(fc, input_fields=None, query="")
                if featClassdf.empty == False:
                    featClassdf['Layer_Name'] = fc
                    print(arcgis_table_to_df(in_fc=fc, input_fields=None, query="").head(n=5))
                    dfList.append(featClassdf)
    dfFinalConcat= pd.concat(dfList, ignore_index=True)
    # Cleaning combined dataframe before export to CSV
    dfFinalConcat = cleanCombinedDataframe(dfFinalConcat, param1)
    try:
        dfFinalConcat.to_csv(outputTable)
        arcpy.AddMessage('Writing to table at: ' + str(outputTable))
    except Exception as e:
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(e))
        arcpy.AddMessage('Writing to table failed. /n/n If error number 13 persists, a csv file in the same location with the same name may be open. To retry, save this file under a different name, or delete this file.')
        
def ScriptTool(param0, param1):
    # Script execution code goes here
    createSelection()
    combineDataframes()
    return
# This is used to execute code if the file was run but not imported
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Tool parameter accessed with GetParameter or GetParameterAsText    
    param0 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    param1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Target polygon: ' + str(param0))
    arcpy.AddMessage('Reference: ' + str(param1))
    ScriptTool(param0, param1)
    
    # Update derived parameter values using arcpy.SetParameter() or arcpy.SetParameterAsText()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be less an answer, and more a check list of things to verify or update.

First, run your service back in Pro or ArcMap. This will help eliminate if the problem is in the app or JavaScript. You don't want to spend days troubleshooting arcpy and the code if it's just a widget issue.

The first rule of writing GP Services (in my words), is to be **explicit**. Sure, `arcpy` allows you to use a workspace and you can discover data from that, but once you publish your tool into the Server, you have little to no insight into where the service is actually looking unless you've put a whole bunch of `arcpy.AddMessages` in. So, my suggestion, instead of doing this:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\fitzpatricko\landChargesSelectTool.gdb"
datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='feature')
for ds in datasets:
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
```

is to NOT use the workspace. Explicitly set the path of your GDB where you need to use it. (Listing datasets)

I'm not sure why you're doing `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True` inside a function. Things like this can lead to unexpected results, especially once you've pushed turned your tool into a service and can't see what's happening. I'd suggest removing it.

You don't pass your inputs into `createSelection` - you assume they're available as global variables. I guess it's working, but again, I'd be explicit. Pass them in from your `__main__ >> ScriptTool` functions.

You have data coming from both `h:\` and `c:\`. You don't mention if you're making use of the Data Store to inform Server about your data. If you are NOT using DS, then these datasets will be copied into the service when you publish. Otherwise, with the DS set, the service should continue to reference them. If you registered the DS folders, I'll make the assumption that the Server **can access** the data. But that's something you may want to double check. Although maybe your `h:\` data is purely output. If that's the case, I'd question why you aren't writing to `arcpy.env.scratchFolder` or `arcpy.env.scratchGDB`

You're handling errors with `try/except` in a couple of places. As you're trying to grab the error `e`, and `arcpy.AddMessage` it, that's good. However, it might be in your best interest to try publishing without *any* error handling. The root cause of the error could be swallowed in your try/except, making it harder to diagnose. In production what you have is a good practice.

I see one instance of `print` in your code. Outputting messages this way will NEVER be accessible in the service messages.

You have **NO OUTPUTS**. Once you get your service to execute successfully, what is the expected result? For someone running this in a webapp, nothing is going to happen in the app for them besides a message saying the tool is done. The GP Service does NOT work directly on the data in the webapp. Yes, you can pass data in the app into the service. OR the GP Service can reference the SAME data that's being used in the app. But this is not a desktop scenario where the tool is working on the SAME data that you have in your map.

I don't know that the above list will fix or make your service work, but it's a bunch of starting pieces to check which will hopefully move your closer to "working"